# JavaScript Implicit Coercion

Tags: javascript, coercion

I'm reading a JavaScript tutorial on implicit and explicit coercion.

What happens in the background with respect to implicit coercion?

```
var a = "42";

var b = a * 1; //this is implicitly coerced to 42 -- the number
```

Does implicit coercion ***ALWAYS*** coerce to a number? What if we wanted to do something a per the below Python example.

I'm getting confused because other languages such as Python would give you a result as per below.

```
a = "3";

b = 9;

print a * b; //This would print 333333333 -- the string
```

Comment: It's going to coerce based on the operation and operands. For example `+` will coerce a string and number to both be strings but with a boolean and number will coerce to number.

Comment: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-type-conversion

Comment: While it's good to familiarize yourself with the concept and general outcomes of implicit coercion in JavaScript, it's not a good idea to rely on these in any sort of production-quality code.

Answer (score 4):

I will leave this here for your convenience to draw some conclusions as far as implicit coercion goes:

```
true + false             // 1
12 / "6"                 // 2
"number" + 15 + 3        // 'number153'
15 + 3 + "number"        // '18number'
[1] > null               // true
"foo" + + "bar"          // 'fooNaN'
'true' == true           // false
false == 'false'         // false
null == ''               // false
!!"false" == !!"true"    // true
['x'] == 'x'             // true 
[] + null + 1            // 'null1'
[1,2,3] == [1,2,3]       // false
{}+[]+{}+[1]             // '0[object Object]1'
!+[]+[]+![]              // 'truefalse'
new Date(0) - 0          // 0
new Date(0) + 0          // 'Thu Jan 01 1970 02:00:00(EET)0'
```

But long story short the rules are such that unless you do an explicit coercion Javascript would do one for you (hence **implicit**) based on the **operation** and the **operand types** involved.

You can check the [JavaScript Coercion Rules](https://delapouite.com/ramblings/javascript-coercion-rules/) table to get a full prospective.

One thing to [note](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/you-dont-know/9781491905159/ch04.html):

> JavaScript coercions always result in one
> of the scalar primitive values, like string, number,
> or boolean. There is no coercion that results in a complex value like
> object or function.

Comment: Link is broken.  Maybe best to juse use 
- https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-type-conversion   ?  I've read a lot of implicit coercion blogs, and most of their explanations are IMO overly verbose and not easy to understand